# error creating array mips

Tags: assembly, mips

I like to make an array with mips by means of syscalls but i get the error Error in D:\mips\create array line 20: Runtime exception at 0x00400028: request (1074003968) exceeds available heap storage (syscall 9).

mine code is:

```
.data
    question1_msg: .asciiz "How much integer do you want to give?\n"
    question2_msg: .asciiz "give a number?\n"
.text

question_numbers:
    la $a0, question1_msg #load the question in $a0
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

answer_numbers: 
    li $v0, 5  #read the anwser of previous question
    syscall
    move $t0, $a0

generate_array:   
    sll $t0, $t0, 2 #create array
    move $a0, $t0
    li $v0, 9
    syscall
    move $t3, $v0 #put the stack pointer in a temperay register

add_numbers_array:
    bge $t1, $t0, exit # if $t1 > $t0 then exit

    #ask questions
    la $a0, question2_msg #load the question in $a0
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    #read numbers
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t2, $a0

    #add number en go to the next array point
    sw $t2, ($t3)
    add $t3, $t3, 4

    #get back to the begin of the loop
    b add_numbers_array


exit :
li $v0 , 10 # let the code end
syscall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this: http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html the integer returned by `syscall 5` is in `$v0`, so you are passing garbage to the next syscall where you try to allocate memory.

Comment: Thanks alot that was a big mistake from mine side. That was the problem now it works almost